# Why does increasing number of threads increase computation time in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to use multiple threads to fetch data from a source. Data item from a fetch call is approximately 150 mb. I simulate that by returning a numpy array of similar size.

In the output of this script, you can see that as I increase the number of worker threads, the time to fetch the data item increases linearly. Shouldn't the call to the function `fetch_data` be independent for each thread? Why is the time taken for this function increasing linearly with the number of threads?

```
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread
from threading import Barrier
from time import perf_counter as pc


def fetch_data():
    # simulating fetching large data item (approximately 150 mb)
    return np.random.random((1000*128, 150))


def producer(barrier, identifier):
    times = []
    for i in range(16):
        t0 = pc()
        data = fetch_data()
        t1 = pc()
        times.append(t1 - t0)
    barrier.wait()
    if identifier == 0:
        print(f'average data fetch time: {sum(times) / len(times)}')


def main(num_workers):
    barrier = Barrier(num_workers)
    producers = [Thread(target=producer, args=(barrier, i)) for i in range(num_workers)]
    for prod in producers:
        prod.start()

    for prod in producers:
        prod.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_worker_options = [1, 2, 4, 8]
    print('--'*25)
    for n in num_worker_options:
        print(f'running with num_workers={n}')
        main(n)
        print('--'*25)
```

**Output**

```
--------------------------------------------------
running with num_workers=1
average data fetch time: 0.1944406289999847
--------------------------------------------------
running with num_workers=2
average data fetch time: 0.37914658368754317
--------------------------------------------------
running with num_workers=4
average data fetch time: 0.7443576513123276
--------------------------------------------------
running with num_workers=8
average data fetch time: 1.4798094858125523
--------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT 1**

Adding more context based on the comments.

I'm building data pipeline that feeds into a neural network. A training step takes about 0.05 seconds where as fetching a batch from local mongodb database takes 5 seconds. I want to optimize the data pipeline such that the bottleneck is the train step that utilizes the gpu and not the dataloading process.

I tried using Pytorch's `DataLoader` which uses `multiprocessing.Process` to parallelize batch creation and filling up a queue that feeds the network. But as I detail in this [github issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/81412), adding more workers doesn't reduce the latency for fetching the batches.

I think this is due to the fact that `multiprocessing` serializes / deserializes data using pickle to communicate between worker and main processes. So if a batch is 150 mb, the overhead to pikcle and unpickle that object is significant. Usually, the parallelism in `torch.DataLoader` is not an issue, because the size of the batch is not hundreds of megabytes.

I then tried to use `multithreading` in a multi-producer, single-consumer design pattern, where multiple background threads would add to a shared queue. The neural network would fetch a batch from the queue and execute the training step. But from the answer, it appears this would not work because threads are concurrent but not parallel.

Any ideas how to achieve parallelism where the objects involved in the worker and main process are large?

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying. The problem with multiprocessing is that since it uses pickle to serialize / deserialize data between the worker and main process, the overhead ends being too much for my use case. What tools are you referring to when you say 'actual parallelism'?

Comment: I realised that an example would be helpful, so I rewrote your example using `multiprocessing` as an answer.

Comment: What is the ratio between training steps and batches read from mongodb? I.e. how many steps for each batch read? Have you tried timing simply reading the data without processing? Because it seems reasonable that most of the time spend is spend on reading the database and performance gains may be achieved by reducing the number of times you go to the database, instead of trying to paralellise the processing.

Comment: 1 batch gets used in 1 training step. It takes 128 records to create a batch. So without any parallelization, it takes ~5 seconds to fetch a batch and then 0.05 seconds to run the training step

Comment: There is not much processing involved, it is just reading the data from the database. To improve that reading latency, I'm looking into converting the data into Parquet format and shard the data into multiple files. I can get improvements in fetching the data, but it will still be a magnitude more than the training step. Hence, I'm looking into ways to parallelize the data loading step. Ideally,  a queue should always be filled at the same rate as a batch gets consumed by the training step

Comment: It depends on how the database is hosted, but it doesn't seem likely that you'll be able to improve performance by creating parallel reads on the database. Unless the database is clustered and multiple readers will be handling your queries, and you're currently limited by the speed of a single reader, I'd sooner expect a slowdown. I get that you're looking at sharding, but that's parallelising a very heavy process. It seems more likely that you'd get performance improvements by reading larger chunks of data at a time, to feed more steps, if at all possible. Hard to say without knowing more.

Comment: The database is hosted locally right now. But I can create clusters if I am able to parallelize with multiple readers. Even if I read larger chunks at a time, the consumption of data is much faster, so the bottleneck would still be the data loading process. I've added a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73071394/4029467) for some high level context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The threads allow concurrency, but not parallelism - they will alternate and do the work concurrently, but they won't use additional cores, so the only gains are in not having to wait for I/O or similar costly operations. As a result, the gains are minimal. Try `multiprocessing` instead - although the overhead is far more costly there, for sufficiently large tasks the actual parallelism will get you what you're looking for.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from time import perf_counter as pc


def fetch_data():
    # simulating fetching large data item (approximately 150 mb)
    return np.random.random((1000*128, 150))


def producer(identifier):
    times = []
    for i in range(16):
        t0 = pc()
        data = fetch_data()
        t1 = pc()
        times.append(t1 - t0)
    if identifier == 0:
        print(f'average data fetch time: {sum(times) / len(times)}')


def main(num_workers):
    ps = [multiprocessing.Process(target=producer, args=(i,)) for i in range(num_workers)]
    for p in ps:
        p.start()
    for p in ps:
        p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_worker_options = [1, 2, 4, 8]

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        for n in num_worker_options:
            print(f'running with num_workers={n}')
            main(n)
            print('--'*25)
```

Output:

```
running with num_workers=1
average data fetch time: 0.1159221250002247
--------------------------------------------------
running with num_workers=2
average data fetch time: 0.11778964999984964
--------------------------------------------------
running with num_workers=4
average data fetch time: 0.13016788124969025
--------------------------------------------------
running with num_workers=8
average data fetch time: 0.14858553749945713
--------------------------------------------------
```

There's some added overhead, but the main difference is that I can hear the fans speeding up for the later number of workers.

For comparison, the first step when running your code on my machine:

```
--------------------------------------------------
running with num_workers=1
average data fetch time: 0.11301828124987878
--------------------------------------------------
```

So, the threaded solution is faster overall than the `multiprocessing` one, for such a trivial task, but not by an awful lot.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this approach but like you mentioned the overhead is quite significant for the actual use case. Were you referring to `multiprocessing` when you said 'actual parallelism' or did you have something else in mind? I'd love to know other alternatives.

Comment: No, as you can tell (and you should try applying this to your code), this is using *actual* paralellism - each `Process` runs on its own core (if your machine has enough of them), more or less independent of the others. Unlike your `Threads` - if you want to learn more, look up threads, processes and the GIL.

Comment: However, if your process is bound by some other bottleneck, it's possible you're just providing a misguiding example - the code you shared simply scales linearly because the load scales linearly. I answered the question you asked, but it sounds like you really have a different problem you're not sharing in your question.

Comment: yes, you are right the question I asked is really to understand the linear scaling of threading. I thought it was parallelizing, but you clarified that it is actually concurrency. I moved from multiprocessing to try threading because scaling number of workers wasn't improving latency. It probably deserves a separate question.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're not really telling us the actual nature of the work you do in your threads / processes and what you're trying to optimise in reality. It's possible that you don't need multiprocessing at all, but you may just have some logical mistakes in asynchronous code, or perhaps you are bound by I/O that cannot be sped up (for example, you can't make a web server faster with more threads / nodes if the limiting factor is the bandwidth of the network connection)

Comment: I've edited the question to give more color on the use case. Curious to see your thoughts.

Comment: As a rarely known case: threads allow parallelism in cpython, if the thread is a direct call to an extension module. These modules can be GIL-free. Some examples are numpy's `pdist` and `squareform` functions. At least, in my test they run in parallel with `pathos` `ThreadingPool().imap`.

Comment: Fortunately, other languages (and even other python implementation) have a decent multithreading system. The concept of multithreading has no requirement of non-paralellism, but with the wide adoption of python (and cpython design choices = GIL), terms became loaded with other meanings. Even  wikipedia sounds a bit misleading, with no references.